# Error: Target id is not valid.

Tags: java, android, automation, android-uiautomator

getting the error while running the following command:

./android create uitest-project -n DeviceTest -t 31 -p ~/Documents/workspace/DeviceTest/

Answer (score 3):

You should provide an correct target Id.

To get the List of target ID's

1. cd to the **tools** directory in your android sdk.
2. Execute **android list target** command

All the available Id's in your android sdk will be listed down. Use any one of the listed target ID.

NOTE: UiAutomator works only on devices supporting API level 16 and above.Therefore, select a target ID which corresponds to "android-16" or above

Answer (score 0):

In a linux environment, find your 'tools' directory (/Documents/tools). Then within the tools directory, type the following command to retrieve all the available IDs and their details in your Android SDK:
**android list target**